# Returning a boolean value in js

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Im trying to use this function to return a value based off of my items.Count

Iv tried various versions of it, all seeming not to work.

This was what i originally tried...

```js
public function IsEmpty():boolean {
    return items.Count == 0;
}
```

Then i tried

```js
public function IsEmpty():boolean {
    if(items.Count == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```js
private function PlaceEmpty(item:Item):boolean{
    if(emptySlots > 0){
        for (var slot:GameObject in allSlots){
            var tmp:Slot = slot.GetComponent(Slot);
            Debug.Log(item.maxSize);

            if(tmp.IsEmpty){ // this is the problem line
            //to get it to work i used (tmp.items.Count < 1)

                tmp.AddItem(item);
                emptySlots--;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `all seeming not to work` what does it do?

Comment: If you log `tmp.IsEmpty` what do you get?

Comment: Is tmp.IsEmpty a `method`? if it is you need to do `tmp.IsEmpty()`

Comment: Log: CompilerGenerated.__Inventory_PlaceEmpty$callable0$74_49__
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Inventory:PlaceEmpty(Item) (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.js:74)
Inventory:AddItem(Item) (at Assets/Scripts/Inventory.js:63)
PlayerGUI:OnTriggerEnter(Collider) (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerGUI.js:55)

Comment: ha...ha...ha yeah i guess adding '()' would help.... ha..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
if(tmp.IsEmpty){
```

it needs to be

```
if(tmp.IsEmpty()){
```